How to find value of 3 inputs
I've made a form that pops up and now I want to store the input values in 3 separate values in the array const book.
The project will be a library app where you'll ultimately be able to remove/add books, and it's apart of The Odin Project's curriculum.
Here is my repository: https://github.com/Rutchyy/library (focus around line 53 in the app.js file.)
const book = submit.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let name = newForm.firstChild.firstChild // How do I navigate to the title input?
    console.log(name)
})

And the HTML:
<form method="get" id="new-book-form">
            <div>
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="author">Author</label>
                <input type="text" id="author" name="author">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="pages">Pages</label>
                <input type="number" id="pages" name="pages">
            </div>
            <button id="create-book">Create Book</button>
        </form>


You need to add the actual code causing the issue in the question.

Done, sorry that I didn't do that in the first place

Don't link out to your repo: have the [mcve] code in your post instead. Your repo should not be necessary to show off the problem you're asking about, not to mention that your repo might be gone next week, or might still be there but the code may have completely changed - changes to third party websites should have zero impact on your post here on Stackoverflow.

submit.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
// book variable be edited afterwards
    let book = []
//select all inputs of the form
    document.querySelectorAll('#new-book-form input').forEach(e =>{
        book.push(e.value)
    })
    console.log(book)
})


At first I created an empty array, then fetched all inputs of the form by querySelectorAll() which selects all elements matching css selector #new-book-form input, then for each of them, I inserted their value to the array.
Hope it helps ^_^

You could use FormData, you can post it directly or use Object.fromEntries() to create an object from it. To create an array from the input values, use [...formData.values()]:


document.getElementById('new-book-form').addEventListener("submit", event => {
    
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const book = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(event.target));
    console.log(book);
    
    const arr = [...new FormData(event.target).values()];
    console.log(arr);
});
<form method="get" id="new-book-form">
            <div>
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="author">Author</label>
                <input type="text" id="author" name="author">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="pages">Pages</label>
                <input type="number" id="pages" name="pages">
            </div>
            <button id="create-book">Create Book</button>
        </form>




Try to use this into your javascript file , as it would be done easily
const books = [];
document.getElementById('create-book').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const title = document.getElementById('title').value;
    const author = document.getElementById('author').value;
    const pages = document.getElementById('pages').value;

    const newBook = { title, author, pages };
    books.push(newBook);

    console.log(books);
});

